# Input selection to a command

Tags: awesome-wm, flite

In this case I want flite (speech synthesizer) to read my selected text when I press a hotkey.
The command is `flite -t "text i want to read"`
How?

Answer (score 1):

Does running `flite -t "$(xclip -o)"` do what you want it to do? If so, you could bind a key to running that:

```
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "r",
        function ()
            awful.spawn.with_shell('flite -t "$(xclip -o)"')
        end,
    ),
```